# Qual é a diferença entre "que" e "quê"?

Tags: ortografia, sintaxe

A dúvida reside em escrever a seguinte frase:

> Em ... consiste esta técnica?

Devo usar *que* ou *quê*? Estava voltado a usar "quê", pois entendia como "algo indeterminado". No entanto, entendo também que o "que" referencia pessoas ou coisas, e, no meu caso, quero dizer algo como "em (qual coisa) consiste esta técnica?".

Estou com bastante dúvida, agradeço se me puderem dar orientação.

Comment: Eu costumo escrever `quê` quando este vier seguindo um artigo definido e indicar "alguma coisa". ex: *O quê é isso?"*. Também soa melhor em frases exclamativas coloquiais que aceitariam dois "que". Ex: *O quê que é isso?!"

Comment: Aqui em Portugal é sempre *em que consiste essa técnica*, ou mais comumente, *no que é que consiste*... Mas nós pronunciamos *que* e *quê* de forma diferente. Portanto só temos que seguir o ouvido.

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado, ficou bem melhor :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A palavra [**que**] é realmente um curinga da Língua Portuguesa, pois pode ser usada em várias situações e com várias funções: pronome, conjunção, substantivo, advérbio, preposição, etc.

Nesse caso usaria [que]. Está antes de um verbo e conseguimos substituir por  "qual coisa" como você diz. [Aqui](http://www.dicio.com.br/que/) tem um exemplo semelhante. Diz que emprega-se [que] "quando se consegue substituir por 'o qual' ou 'a qual': o hotel, que consideram o melhor, é um paraíso". O Dicionário Aulete diz que "antes de um verbo, podem ocorrer 'que' ou 'o que', sendo este último o mais usado".

Já [**quê**] empregado-se no caso de substantivo, pronome interrogativo, interjeição ou expressão interrogativa, como descreve o Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa:

> **quê** 
>   (latim quem)
>   **substantivo masculino**
>   1. Dificuldade, complicação (ex.: ainda há uns quês por resolver).
>   2. Alguma coisa (ex.: acho que isto tem um quê de subversão).
>   **pronome interrogativo**
>   3. Expressão usada para questionar o que foi dito anteriormente ou como pedido de repetição do que foi dito (ex.: Quê? Não percebi...). = COMO, O QUÊ
>   **interjeição**
>   4. Expressão usada, com .entonação interrogativa, para indicar espanto ou contrariedade (ex.: Quê?! Ainda não acabou?). = O QUÊ
>
> "que", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/que [consultado em 30-04-2016].

O seu [que] não tem essas funções. Parece ter a função de conjunção, e não leva acento.

Comment: Qual è que é a diferença entre um pronome interrogativo e uma 'expressão interrogativa', mesmo?