# "Que" interrogativo

Tags: ortografia, gramática, uso-de-palavras

Umas das expressões que eu mais vejo em inglês é:

> What are you doing?

E uma de suas muitas possíveis traduções é o básico:

> O que você está fazendo?

Porém o curinga ***que*** quando indica um substantivo deve ser acentuado:

> O quê você está fazendo?

Pois quem faz, faz alguma coisa, mas [pelo que eu li](http://www.tudosobreconcursos.com/materiais/portugues/usos-da-palavra-que) o ***que*** interrogativo não deve ser acentuado eu eu fiquei na dúvida.

Pensei em combinar os dois:

> O quê é que você está fazendo?

Mas além de não saber se isso está correto, caso sim, não sei se isso seria culto demais para se usar ao transcrever algo dito no dia-a-dia.

Além disso, no mesmo link acima é dito que não se dever usar artigos definidos quando usando o ***que*** como pronome interrogativo. Por quê?

Comment: A questão é ligeiramente diferente [desta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3186/1139)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nos teus exemplos é sempre ***que***, nunca ***quê***, e não há problema nenhum com ***o que***:

> **O que** você está fazendo?
>   **O que *é que*** você está fazendo?

Vejamos as questões uma a uma.

---

### “*Que*” versus “*Quê*”

Existe o **substantivo *quê***, mas não tem função interrogativa. Usamo-lo para referir algo que não conseguimos explicar ou definir bem. Vejamos o que diz o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/qu%C3%AA):

> **2.** Alguma coisa; qualquer coisa: *Ela tem um **quê** de mistério: Ele tem alguns **quês** que me desagradam.*

Depois existem os **pronomes interrogativos *que*** e ***quê***. Semanticamente são a mesma coisa. A diferença é que usamos *quê* no fim de frase e *que* no meio ou princípio para refletir a entoação das frases:

> ***O que*** você está fazendo? versus *Você está fazendo **o quê?***
>
> *Por **que** não dizes nada?* versus *Não dizes nada por **quê?***
>
> *De **que** te queixas?* versus *Queixas-te de **quê?***

No fim de frase o pronome interrogativo é tónico, é pronunciado com ênfase especial; por isso é *quê* e não *que*. No meio ou princípio da frase é átono, não recebe ênfase especial. Esta diferença já foi discutida [nesta pergunta sobre *por que amanhã* versus *por quê amanhã*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/vais-embora-amanh%C3%A3-por-qu%C3%AA-amanh%C3%A3-ou-por-que-amanh%C3%A3-em-portugu%C3%AAs-bra?noredirect=1&lq=1). No português europeu existe uma diferença adicional entre *que* e *quê*, que facilita tudo. Enquanto no Brasil, *que* e *quê* são ambos pronunciados /ke/, em Portugal *quê* é também pronunciado /ke/ [(podem ouvir portuguese e brasileiros no Forvo)](https://forvo.com/word/qu%C3%AA/#pt), mas *que* é /kɨ/ [(ouçam o usuário aimae no Forvo)](https://pt.forvo.com/word/que/#pt).

---

### “*Que*” versus “*O que*”

Nos exemplos anteriores, o interrogativo *que* significa ‘que coisa’ e é por isso chamado *pronome substantivo*. Noutros casos, significa aproximadamente ‘que espécie de’ e é por isso chamado *pronome adjetivo*:

> ***Que*** mal te fiz eu?
>
> ***Que*** negócio é esse?
>
> ***Que*** filme queres ver?

Este *que* pronome adjetivo não pode ser substituído por *o que*: não se pode dizer “*o que mal te fiz eu?*” ou *o que negócio é esse?*” Agora, o [site lincado na pergunta (27-12-2016)](http://www.tudosobreconcursos.com/materiais/portugues/usos-da-palavra-que) vai mais longe e diz que “a língua culta não admite perguntas como ‘O que você disse?’” Ou seja desaconselha *o que* mesmo quando *que* é pronome substantivo. Pelos vistos isto é, ou foi, uma guerra antiga. Mas nós podemos ignorá-la. Não encontrei nenhum dicionário ou gramática que defendesse esta interdição. Pelo contrário, a *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* da parelha luso-brasileira Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa 2014, p. 441-2) diz:

> **2.** Para dar maior ênfase à pergunta, em lugar de *que* pronome substantivo, usa-se *o que:*
>
> > O mundo? **O que** é o mundo, ó meu amor? (Florbela Espanca, *S[onetos*, 1962], 90.)
>
> […]
>
> Nenhuma razão assiste aos que condenam a anteposição do *o* ao *que* interrogativo, como exaustivamente mostraram Heráclito Graça, em *Factos da linguagem*. Rio de Janeiro, Livraria de Viúva Azevedo, 1904, p. 367-383; e Said Ali, em *Dificuldades da língua portuguesa* […] e *Gramática histórica da língua portuguesa* […]

---

### Que é que

Finalmente, podemos também acrescentar um *é que* expressivo à questão, dando o “*o que é que você está fazendo?*” Como diz também a *Nova Gramática* (p. 442):

> **3.** Tanto uma como outra forma [*que* e *o que*] pode ser reforçada por *é que:*
>
> > —**Que é que** o senhor está fazendo? gritou-lhe. (Clarice Lispector, [*A maçã no escuro*], 313.)
> >
> > **O que é que** eu vejo, nestas tardes tristes? (Teixeira de Pascoaes, [*Obras completas*] III, 24.)

Este ***é que*** já foi abordado [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3268/n%C3%B3s-%C3%A9-quem-agradecemos-ou-n%C3%B3s-%C3%A9-que-agradecemos). É um mero elemento expressivo, e não tem nada de especialmente culto. Em Portugal, especialmente na linguagem coloquial, ouvirás muito mais *o que **é que** estás a fazer?* do que simplesmente *o que estás a fazer?* Já reparei que no Brasil o seu uso não é tão comum como em Portugal, embora, como em tantas outras coisas possa haver diferenças regionais: o [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/2008/) regista um quantidade impressionante de *o que é que* na imprensa do Recife.

Comment: Este último exemplo de 'quê' não é apenas pelo simples fato de ser interrogativo ou estar no fim de frase, mas é por se tornar tônico nesses casos que ele recebe acento. O 'que' substantivando é quase o mesmo caso do xis 'Este é o xis da questão'.

Comment: @André Sim, essa é sempre a verdadeira razão: usas-se o pronome *quê* em vez do *que*, quando ele é tónico. Mas é mais fácil de ver se vem no fim da frase do que ver se é tónico.

Comment: Não vou mentir que foi uma resposta fácil de entender mas, então, a grosso modo (mesmo), basicamente é o mesmo caso do por que / por quê, acentuando apenas no final. A ênfase que eu tentei dar combinando os dois, desde sempre esteve errada e, agora, sem acentos, me parece culto demais pra uma coisa dita no dia-a-dia.

Comment: @Bruno Sim, o *que/quê* são os mesmos em "***que** estás fazendo?*" / "*estás fazendo o **quê?***" e em "*por **que** não vens?*" / "*não vens por **quê?***". Ou ainda "*de **que** te queixas?*" / "*queixas-te de **quê?***". Qualquer coisa que esteja nebulosa, diz, que eu tento clarificar.

Comment: Quanto ao *que **é que** você está fazendo?* tens que ver é se é algo que ouves com alguma frequência no dia a dia. Se ouvires, é assim que se escreve, sem acentos. O [Corpus do Português](http://corpus.byu.edu/), na época atual, tem muitos exemplos de *o que é que* de Portugal e do Recife, mas relativamente poucos do resto do Brasil.