# Função da palavra "que" repetida em "o que que você está fazendo?"

Tags: conjunções

Qual seria a função da primeira palavra "que" na seguinte frase:

- O *que* que você está fazendo?

Comment: Postei uma resposta e acabei removendo-a, mas deixarei um *link* com ela: <https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/5915.md>. Caso ajude-o, postarei como resposta.

Comment: Na norma culta podes escrever "o que você está fazendo?" ou "o que é que você está fazendo?" embora na linguagem oral coloquial "o que é que" seja normalmente "comprimido"; em Portugal pode soar simplesmente como "o kék você está fazendo?" Creio que a resposta a [esta pergunta sobre o " 'que' interrogativo"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/que-interrogativo) responde à tua pergunta.

Comment: Em Portugal, as interrogativas-Q diretas sem "é que" precisam de inversão. Por isso, quando muito "O que está você fazendo?". Mas a pergunta é sobre o uma putativa frase "O que que você está fazendo?"? Essa frase não é possível.

Comment: @Artefacto A frase *O que que você está fazendo?*, ao meu ver, é possível. Seria uma forma reduzida de *O que é que você está fazendo?*. O verbo *ser* (subentendido) + *que*, nesse caso, forma uma partícula de realce. Fiz um texto <https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/5915.md>, mas não sei se cabe nesta pergunta.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Achei fantástica a sua resposta no GitHub! Obrigado!!!

Comment: @Artefacto eu tentei escrever sem o () mas o StackExchange não aceitou, não sei porque. Quando pus () ele aceitou a pergunta.

Comment: @Jacinto você tem razão, falamos tanto "que que" que eu nem havia pensado que faltava o "é" entre eles. "O que que você quer?" seria o mesmo que "O que é que você quer?".

Comment: Marcelo, foi isso que eu imaginei, que o teu "que que" era o "que é que". Imagino que em muitos sotaques brasileiros a diferença entre os dois seja muito ligeira, não? Em Portugal podes ouvir "o kiék" ou "o kék", mas eu vejo isso como duas maneiras de pronunciar "o que é que".

Comment: @Artefacto, concordo, em Portugal dirias "o que estás tu a fazer?" e não "o que tu estás a fazer?" mas creio que no Brasil é comum "o que tu estás/você está...?"

Comment: `O que que você está fazendo` não tem lógica gramatical nenhuma!

Comment: O @Jacinto explicou muito bem o que eu não consegui explicar devido às regras do StackExchange (tive que colocar um dos que's entre parenteses), no colóquio brasileiro usamos "que que", que na verdade deveria ser corretamente dito "que é que", portanto tem lógica sim.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Acho a sua resposta muito relevante, assim como o OP - não quer reconsiderar sua deleção?

Answer (score 1):

### Resposta Breve

O primeiro **que** — no contexto apresentado — desempenha a função de núcleo do complemento da locução verbal *está fazendo*. Diferente do segundo *que*. Esse representa uma partícula expletiva.

> O que você está fazendo? => Você está fazendo o quê? (Quem está fazendo, está fazendo **algo**)

> Observação: O segundo *que* é uma partícula expletiva.

### Análise

```
 O  que   é que   você   está fazendo?
└┬┘└─┬─┘ └──┬──┘ └─┬─┘  └──────┬──────┘
 │   │      │      │           │        
 │   │      │      │           └────────── Locução Verbal
 │   │      │      └────────────────────── Núcleo do sujeito
 │   │      └───────────────────────────── Partícula Expletiva
 │   └──────────────────────────────────── Núcleo do Objeto Direto
 └──────────────────────────────────────── Adjunto Adnominal
```

### Partícula Expletiva

**O que (que) você está fazendo?** é uma forma reduzida de **O que (é que) você está fazendo?**.

O termo **é que** é uma *partícula de realce* — também conhecida como *partícula expletiva*. Essa partícula não exerce função gramatical.

```
┌─────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│Nós [é que] sabemos viver        │Nós sabemos viver         │
├─────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│Quanto [que] é a conta?          │Quanto é a conta?         │
├─────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────┤
│O que [é que] você está fazendo? │O que você está fazendo?  │
└─────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Normalmente é utilizada com o verbo *ser* + conjunção *que*, porém — em casos de lugar ou tempo, é substituído por *onde* e *quando*.

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────────────────┐
│No Recife [é onde] fez o primário.                 │No Recife fez o primário                │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────┤
│Durante a chuva [é quando] ocorrem mais acidentes. │Durante a chuva ocorrem mais acidentes. │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

> **Observação:** Como vimos nos exemplos, às vezes o verbo **ser** pode está subentendido.

Entretanto é necessário ter cuidado ao fazer a análise da frase ou oração. De acordo com o gramático Evanildo Bechara, a junção do verbo **ser** + o pronome **que** pode indicar:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ TERMO                                      │ EXEMPLO                                         │ OBSERVAÇÃO                  │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ é + que (conj. integrante)                 │ “A verdade é que saíram.”                       │ --                          │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ é (verbo vicário) + que (conj. integrante) │ “Que quer dizer este nome? (É que) as almas...” │ É que = quer dizer que      │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ é (vicário) + que (conj. causal)           │ “Por que veio? (É que) teve medo”               │ É que = veio porque         │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┤
│ é que = é o que                            │ “Este livro (é que) lemos ontem”                │ É que = é o que lemos ontem │
└────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

Para diferenciar, é necessário verificar se o termo se encaixa nos exemplos supra e se a remoção dele compromete o sentido da frase.

Comment: Caramba!! Escrevi o texto e depois percebi que era o primeiro termo. Apesar disso resolvi deixar, ao menos por ora.

Comment: No Brasil, o termo "o que é que ..." ou "o que que ..." é comumente utilizado na região nordeste, principalmente em interiores. Faz sentido? Isso é questionável. A gramática permite? Sim.

Answer (score 1):

É só uma redução da expressão **"O que é que"**, onde o "é" foi omitido.

PS: Sei que isso já foi dito dentro de outras respostas, mas às vezes a pessoa prefere uma explicação mais simples.

Answer (score 0):

Partícula realçadora.

Nesta [referência](https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/particulas-expletivas-ou-realce.htm), ela coloca o segundo *"que"* (e não o primeiro; de fato, na fala, o primeiro é mais enfatizado) com esta função, que também é chamada de "partícula expletiva ou partícula de realce, expressão expletiva ou expressão de realce."

A partícula *"que"* comumente aparece após conjunções e advérbios:

- Desde cedo que aguardava por notícias.
- Enquanto que as torcidas brigavam, não havia polícia no estádio.
- Havia muito que não tirava férias.

Nos exemplos abaixo, a partícula serve para realçar o sujeito ("você"):

- Você que fez este trabalho?
- "Você é muito bonito!" | "Você que é!

Esta segunda [referência](https://materiais.portuguescompestana.com.br/o-que-e-particulaexpressao-expletiva/) tem muitos outros exemplos.

Complementando, também é comum dizer *"o que é que"*. Veja, por exemplo, a letra da canção [Essa Tal Liberdade (Só Pra Contrariar)](https://www.letras.mus.br/so-pra-contrariar/85/):

> *O que é que* eu vou fazer com essa tal liberdade / se estou na solidão pensando em você

Answer (score 0):

Agora que li melhor e vi que é o segundo "que" que está também em questão, vou melhorar a resposta.

O **primeiro** "o que" é, sim, o pronome interrogativo da oração, que substitui "o que está sendo feito" pelo interlocutor. Este elemento é, naturalmente, movido para o início da oração.

O **segundo** "que", no entanto, segundo as teorias mais recentes de sintaxe, é um complementador que ocupa o núcleo do sintagma complementador. Em termos simples: ele ocupa um espaço na sentença que o português parece pedir preenchimento e que só as palavras já presentes não bastam. Isto é um fato que gramáticas escolares e outros materiais mais simplificados não contemplam e que explicam fenômenos muito mais profundos

Este fenômeno acontece na língua portuguesa no geral, inclusive, em Portugal pesquisadores dizem que é justamente a presença deste segundo elemento "é que" que permite a manutenção desta ordem da frase (caso contrário seria "o que faz o João?" ao invés de "o que é que o João faz?), e ocorre também até em outras línguas, como o francês!